# How can I copy an R chart to the clipboard in Linux

Tags: r

In the Windows version of R, I can right click on any chart and copy it to the clipboard:

```
> windows(5, 5)
> plot(rnorm(100))
```

[image]

In Linux, I don't get the same right-clickability, nor do I even get the menus in the graphical window which allow me, under Windows, to save the chart under various graphical formats.

I know I can do png("filename.png", 5, 5) for example to get the file out, but can I actually just copy an x11 or Cairo graphical device output to the clipboard as in R for Windows?

Comment: This likely depends on your window manager, but you could take a screenshot of the window and save that...

Comment: Okay. I'm using i3 so I guess I need to use scrot or something. There is no way to do this in R directly, even as a command for example something like > clipboard(5, 5) as a graphical device?

Comment: I guess this is a feature of the R GUI for Windows. I don't think this is possible unless you are using an IDE, like RStudio.